# Access original Mongodb data of a Django Model

Tags: django, mongodb, django-nonrel

I'm using django-nonrel in combination with mongodb-engine. It's working perfect if all the fields stored in a mongodb object are also defined on the model.

But i've got some extra data on the mongodb object, which are not set on the model. And that's my problem. For now i do an extra query to get the original mongodb object, like so:

```
collection = connection.get_collection(self._meta.db_table)
self._mongo_data = collection.find_one({'_id': ObjectId(self.pk)})
```

It works fine, but isn't that efficient because this is the second time this query runs (first for the creation of the model and later to get the original mongodb data).

Is there a way to access the original data, retrieved for creating the model?

*Setting these extra fields on the model isn't a option, because extra data is created on the fly.*

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a good way to do this.

The fields selected are limited at query time to the fields in the model:

https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine/blob/master/django_mongodb_engine/compiler.py#L123

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/sql/query.py#L1638

Can you use a dict field/embedded object and have some kind of document level namespace to grab these from?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I found out i can add the extra mongo data to the resultset, unfortunately this extra data gets lost once the model is created:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L298

Comment: I think your best bet is to take the extra data and embed it using a embedded document or a dict field.

Answer (score 1):

If there's a way to do this using a SQL database and it doesn't work with MongoDB Engine, please open a bug report. Otherwise I'm afraid you need to get this feature into Django first :-)